# CSS/JS not loading. CSS/JS broken

Tags: javascript, css, magento, caching, magento-1.9

I just recently restored a backup i had. And after the restoring i logged in to my admin panel and got an message that

> I need to "update my cache"

. So i updated the cache and also flushed it.

After that was done i went to my Website and there were no CSS or Jss, or at least it was broken. This have happend before but i got it fixed by changing the premissions to the skin and media folder. But this time it don't work.

I realy need this fixed without getting the error again.

Comment: Do you have css/js files in your directory? What are you imports?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1) Go to admin section

2) Go to System->Configuration->ADVANCED->Developer

3) Set “Merge JavaScript Files” and “Merge CSS Files” to **No**

4) Flush Javascript/CSS Cache at Cache management admin interface.

I hope this solved your problem.